# gdb warnings: "Memory read failed" and "cannot close core: File truncated"

Tags: debugging, gdb, coredump, core-file

I wan't to create a core dump file with gdb. When I issue the command `generate-core-file` during a gdb session, this results in the following warnings:

`warning: Memory read failed for corefile section, 1048576 bytes at 0x400317f0.
warning: cannot close "core.42000": File truncated
Saved corefile core.42000`

The file then always has a size of 210K. So there seems to be some limit which restrains gdb to produce corefiles larger than 210K.

I also set `ulimit -c unlimited` with the bash and controlled it with `ulimit -a` which gives `core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited`.
But gdb seems to ignore this as I am getting a truncated core file.
Then, in the file /etc/security/limits.conf, I set the values for hard and soft core to unlimited, too. But nothing changes.

Does anybody have an idea how I can create larger ( >210K) core files on my system (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)?

Many thanks in advance and best regards.

Comment: Can you run `(gdb) info proc mappings` to see what the memory around 0x400317f0 is mapped to? Maybe it belongs to a file that the program no longer has access to, or to a device whose driver doesn't support access by ptrace.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick when I run `(gdb) info proc mappings <pid>` I get `warning: unable to open /proc file '/proc/<pid>/maps'`, and I am not able to get gdb open that file. But when opening it manually and searching for the memory address at which gdb failed to read the core file section, I find that the file starts and ends with much larger addresses, meaning that the relevant memory address does not lie in this range. Or am I interpreting something wrong? The /proc/<pid>/maps file looks like the following:

Comment: @MarkPlotnick
`5617c31e3000-5617c382e000 r-xp 00000000 fc:02 9467963                    /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
5617c3a2d000-5617c3b81000 r--p 0064a000 fc:02 9467963                    /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
5617c3b81000-5617c3bf5000 rw-p 0079e000 fc:02 9467963                    /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
5617c3bf5000-5617c4086000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
5617c5ab5000-5617c76ec000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7f3240000000-7f3240201000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
[....]
`

Oh, sorry, I just saw that the file content here looks very bad formatted.

Comment: Can you run that info proc mappings command while gdb is debugging that qemu process (the same process that gcore has trouble with)? The addresses may be different during different runs of the program, especially if started outside of gdb (because gdb disables ASLR).

Comment: I already ran the info proc mappings command while gdb was debugging this qemu process. Do you have any idea why gdb can't open the file? Or is there any other way to get to the correct addresses?

Comment: Does `info proc mappings` - just that, no pid argument - also fail?

Comment: If I do that, gdb is telling me "Can't determine the current process's PID: you must name one", wherefore I added the PID of the qemu process. And then the already mentioned `warning: unable to open /proc file '/proc/<pid>/maps'` appears.

Comment: Hmm. Are you running gdb to debug a bare-metal machine being emulated by qemu, using qemu's gdbserver?

Comment: I am running gdb from my Ubuntu host to debug a little self developed OS in Rust.
qemu is started as follows:
`./qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=bootimage.bin -s -S -m 1024M -enable-kvm -serial file:logs/TRACE_$(TIME)`

gdb is then started as follows:
`./rust-os-gdb/bin/rust-gdb "target/x86_64-rtos/debug/rtos" -ex "target remote :1234"`

Maybe it's important to note that I patched gdb to be able to debug the Rust operating system -> 
https://github.com/phil-opp/binutils-gdb#gdb-for-64-bit-rust-operating-systems

Comment: Thanks, that answers all my questions. My initial questions assumed that you were trying to get a core image of a Linux process. But, I don't have any knowledge about how well gdb can generate a core image of a bare-metal debugging target, sorry. I will look at the rust-os-aware gdb you're using  if I have a chance.

Comment: Ok, maybe you 'll find something useful. Thanks anyway!